# Machine learning or deep learning for SAT score prediction?

Tags: database, machine-learning, deep-learning, prediction

I want to predict SAT scores of a test taker , say X who has taken 20 mock SATs. I have 100s of datasets(100 testtakers). Is there any model or library that can be used to learn / train it on 100 datasets and then predict the score of one dataset? If yes , should I use machine learning or deep learning for this?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited amount of info you have provided, I tend to say you are better off with a linear regression or decision tree model (depending on the input features and the amount of non-linearity). I do not imagine 100 data samples is sufficient enough to train a deep learning model. 
Besides, if you can solve your problem with the simplest model, there is no reason to try a more complex model.